# Visual Studio 2015 Silverlight Ria Services project references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional, and it installed correctly. But starting to work on a Silverlight project, I had a problem with the RIA Services proxy project in my solution (the silverlight project that references the RIA servies server project). The project builds and runs successfully, but it shows 'cannot find reference' errors everywhere I reference classes from my server project, like it doesn't recognize the generated file .g.cs, so I can't work on my RIA Services classes on the client. Anyone had this problem too ??

Comment: It happened in the past and might be fixed by removing the old reference from this project and add it back after that.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work too

Comment: A temporary "fix" for me was to click the "show all files", navigate to the .g.cs and click refresh for that file. Works until the next clean. Impractical in many solutions though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have the same problem.  I filed a bug with repro at Microsoft's Connect site: [types in referenced RIA silverlight projects are not recognized in VS 2015](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1663726/types-in-referenced-ria-silverlight-projects-are-not-recognized-in-vs-2015)

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem,

1. clean all  projects,
2. go to soulation folder and delete this folders ==>"obj"&"bin"
3. remove all extention rference and web refrence from silverlight project,
4. add all refrence agian
5. rebuild project

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work too. I tried all the steps above but the problem persists. The project builds successfully, but in the development it doesn't recognize all the classes contained in the RIA services generated file .g.cs

Comment: search in error, and find error without .g.cs, there are 1 or more, if fixed this error then with clean and rebuild project, you can run project